# Use only time part of pattern

Tags: android, jodatime

I'm using Joda in  my android application to parse and show some dates. I let the users specify their own DateTime pattern which is working super!

However, if I got an date that is today or tomorrow I would like to show "Today 20:10" where 20:10 uses thir predefined pattern.

The code I tried is:

> parsedDateTime.withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault()).toLocalTime().toString(dateTimeFormatter)

Where parsedDateTime is my parsed DateTime object and dateTimeFormatter the custom pattern.

I was hoping that it would use only the time because of the .toLocalTime(), it kind of does. It gives me the time just eight but it's showing some strange boxes with question marks in them for the date.

Answer (score 0):

You should let the user define 2 patterns: Date and Time. You then combine them with a space when printing a DateTime value.

Comment: Thanks man, I think that would have to be my last restort though, most of the users have a custom pattern setup already and I would hate to have them change it again :)